# How to refresh AWS temporary credentials from within an app running in EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

We have a java app that runs within an EC2. This uses AWS SDK to interact with AWS services. The app uses the default credentials provider which in turn uses the temporary tokens from the EC2.

The problem is that this temporary token expires after a while and all subsequent AWS SDK calls fail. How can we refresh this temporary credentials so that the app can use the new valid credentials?

Answer (score 4):

`InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider` retrieves credentials as needed; a client using it should never see a credentials timeout exception.

This implies that either (1) you are explicitly setting instance profile credentials on the client that is timing out, or (2) there is something else in the  [provider chain](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/credentials.html#credentials-default) that is providing limited-time credentials.

Or, I suppose, you might be using an extremely old version of the SDK. I don't know at what point they added automatic refresh; according to [git blame](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blame/master/aws-java-sdk-core/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/auth/InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider.java), the fetcher variable was last changed 13 months ago. But I've been using instance credentials with long-running processes for much longer than that.

Answer (score 3):

This [article](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/security-token-expired/) may help you.

If you really need to get a new credentials, the following example shows pseudocode for how to use temporary security credentials if you're using an AWS SDK:

```
assumeRoleResult = AssumeRole(role-arn);
tempCredentials = new SessionAWSCredentials(
   assumeRoleResult.AccessKeyId, 
   assumeRoleResult.SecretAccessKey, 
   assumeRoleResult.SessionToken);
s3Request = CreateAmazonS3Client(tempCredentials);
```

Read further info about temporary credentials in [this docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_temp_use-resources.html).

Comment: Yes as Teddy said this how to assume a role and get temporary credentials, but regarding refreshing the credentials, You must make sure that you get a new set of credentials before the old ones expire. In some SDKs, you can use a provider that manages the process of refreshing credentials for you; check the documentation for the SDK you're using.